# javascript foreach object and get the result in a state

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am iterating over an object from firestore subcollection and I can only console log the result, but I am not able to add the result in a state to use it in a flat list. I tried many ways to get the result in an array but no success.

```
  const [order, setOrder] = useState()
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchOrder = async()=>{
        const orderRef = doc(db, "Order", route.params.orderId)
        const orderCollectionRef =  collection(orderRef, "products")
        const q = await query(orderCollectionRef)
        const getOrder =await getDocs(q)
        getOrder.forEach(doc=>{
            console.log(doc.data())

            //i can console log the result but i want to get it in a state to use it in flatlist
        })
        
        
    } 
    fetchOrder()
},[])
```

this is the console log of getOrder [image]

and this is the console log of doc.data()
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   const fetchOrder = async()=>{
        const orderRef = doc(db, "Order", route.params.orderId)
        const orderCollectionRef =  collection(orderRef, "products")
        const q = await query(orderCollectionRef)
        const getOrder =await getDocs(q)
        let orders = []
        getOrder.forEach(doc=>{
            //this is the right way to push the orders to an array
            orders.push({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            })
        })
        setOrder(orders)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see example in in this main page site, i saw something similar that work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, creating a temp array then push the orders using forEach, then using setState.

```
const getOrder =await getDocs(q)
const temp = []
getOrder.forEach(doc=>{
            temp.push(doc.data()))
setOrder(temp)
```

I am not sure whether if you want to have it in the right order as the original, for safe, you may also consider to use 'for await of' instead of forEach

Comment: Actually I tried this approach before posting my question, but it didn't work

Comment: can you add on what is the type of doc.data() returns, 
what is the result of logging out the array using this approach?

Comment: Also, it will be helpful to tell what is the type / example that the constant getOrder returns

Comment: this is the result i get when i console log the doc.data(). LOG   {"productPrice": 325, "productTitle": "الة حاسبة"}
 LOG  {"productPrice": 36.35, "productTitle": "رزمة ورق تصوير 80 جرام"}
 LOG  {"productPrice": 36.25, "productTitle": "حافظة بلاستيك بكبسولة"}

Comment: and this is the result if i console log the getOrder ---  i will edit my question with the result becasue it is too long to be added in a comment